# remove duplicates from sorted array - trying to understand an answer (leetcode)

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I'm trying to answer the Leetcode question "[Remove duplicates from sorted array](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/?envType=study-plan-v2&envId=top-interview-150)" , and I am not sure I understand the logic. This is the challenge :

> Given an integer array nums sorted in non-decreasing order, remove the
> duplicates in-place such that each unique element appears only once.
> The relative order of the elements should be kept the same. Then
> return the number of unique elements in nums.
>
> Consider the number of unique elements of nums to be k, to get
> accepted, you need to do the following things:
>
> Change the array nums such that the first k elements of nums contain
> the unique elements in the order they were present in nums initially.
> The remaining elements of nums are not important as well as the size
> of nums. Return k.

And this is one of the answers:

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        i,j=0,1
        while i<=j and j<len(nums):
            if nums[i]==nums[j]:
                j+=1
            else:
                nums[i+1]=nums[j]
                i+=1
        return i+1
```

What I don't manage to get is this :

```
            if nums[i]==nums[j]:
                j+=1
```

**imagine we have this list of nums  [1,1,2,3,5,6,7,7,8,7],**

**why if value at index i == value at index j we only add 1 to j?
what I understand from this script is that it doesn't remove any duplicate (1,1), it just changes j to be 2 , and i is still smaller than j (while loop),
what am I missing here ?**

I was trying to do something like this but it fails due to index error  (I understand why but haven't solved it yet) :

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicate(self, 
                      nums: list, 
                      ) -> int:
        k=1

        for i in range(1,len(nums)):
            print(i,i-1)
            print(nums)
            if nums[i] == nums[i-1]: 
                
                del nums[i]

        return k



solution_instance = Solution()

nums = [1,1,2,3,5,6,7,7,8,7]
solution_instance.removeDuplicate(nums)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        nums[:] = dict.fromkeys(nums)
        return len(nums)
```

The result on leetcode after submitting:

[image]

Comment: thanks I liked your answer! did you understood also the solution posted on my original post?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you wanna calculate only k, simple to achieve that. Refer below

```
class Solution:
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums:list) -> int:
        uniq_list=list(set(nums))
        k=len(uniq_list)          
        return k
solu=Solution()
lis=[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
print(solu.removeDuplicates(lis)) #output value 5
```

Comment: set already implements deduplication, I think it is not valid, as you did not solved anything